# Ejemplo que dispara el error: "Invalid Syntax"

Tags: python

Estoy empezando a aprender a programar en Python a través de un libro. Me pusieron este ejemplo pero cuando intento correr el programa me aparece "Invalid Syntax".

```
>>> userInput= input("Enter 1 or 2:")
Enter 1 or 2:
        if userInput == "1":
    print("Hello World")
    print("How are you")
    elif userInput == "2":
    print("Python Rocks")
    print("I love Python")
        else:
    print("You did not enter a valid number")
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema lo tienes al principio el input en su sintaxis no lleva **":"** al final, tampoco puedes colocar fuera de sus paréntesis un string como el que has colocado **"Enter 1 or 2"**. Es por esto que te dice **"invalid syntax"**.

También comentarte que lo que hace **input()** es recibir valores ingresados por el usuario a través del teclado.

Aquí he corregido tu código:

```
print("Enter 1 or 2")
userInput= input() 
if userInput == "1": 
    print("Hello World") 
    print("How are you") 
elif userInput == "2": 
    print("Python Rocks") 
    print("I love Python") 
else: 
    print("You did not enter a valid number")
```

**Nota:** En python es muy importante identar ya que si no lo haces bien la consola también te arrojará error por ello.